# GET / POST request in JavaScript for pie charts using chartist

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get, chartist.js

I'm trying to code a statistics pie with JavaScript

```
Chartist.Pie('#forumCharts', {
  labels: ['6%','12%','1%'],
  series: [6, 12, 1]
});
```

Above is a bit of the code, the pie is working perfectly but I want to call my API over the GET or POST method that returns an `int` that I can use in the sections `labels:` & `series:`

I have tried multiple posts from Stack Overflow but nothing works for me.

```
http://api.maija.ga/get_response.php/?key=<myKey>&q=members
```

Comment: can you show us what you did try so we can help improve it? Did you attempt a GET request? It would also help if you could give example data on what the API returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get information ( labels or series ) from your endpoint to draw the pie chart, if it is you can get information using ajax GET request.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://api.maija.ga/get_response.php/?key=<key>&q=members",
   success: function(response)
   {
      // alert(response); // show response from the php script.
      Chartist.Pie('#forumCharts', {
           labels: response.labels,
           series: response.series
      });       
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: you should include some kind of explanation with your answer. Code only answers don't add much value.

Comment: @AndrewLohr sure will do :)

Comment: thanks, how should look the get_response.php?
At the moment the page only shows an int like 7, and q=threads shows another int but i need both, how can i solve this?

Comment: @getServer Refer the api properly it may tell you how get what you want.